# Promises resolved before all inner promise resolved, multiple async API calls

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Hi I'm new to the react/redux development environment so I appreciate any help.

I'm trying to make 2 API calls asynchronously when `componentDidMount` by calling `dispatch(fetchAllPositions(selectedUserDivision))` in my app.js

I found a suggested method in [this post](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/723) and the `fetchAllPositions` function wraps two action functions together in a `Promise.all`

```
export function fetchAllPositions(division) {
  return dispatch => Promise.all([
        dispatch(fetchUserPositionsIfNeeded(division)),
        dispatch(fetchDefaultPositionsIfNeeded(division))
    ])
    .then(console.log("fetched both"))
}
```

The two action functions are nearly identical, they just call a slightly different API url. One of them looks like the follows, where the `shouldFetchUserPosition` is just a pure function that returns a boolean:

```
function fetchUserPositions(division) {
  return dispatch => {
      const url = apiOptions.server + `/api/user/position?division=${division}`
      dispatch(requestUserPositions(division))
    return fetch(url, options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(receiveUserPositions(division,json)),
        err => console.log(err))

  }
}

export function fetchUserPositionsIfNeeded(division) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (shouldFetchUserPositions(getState(), division)) {
      return dispatch(fetchUserPositions(division))
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve()
    }
  }
}
```

The logic is that for an update, a `REQUEST...` action is sent while pulling data, then a `RECEIVE...` action is sent when data is ready to be updated into the new state.

The trouble is that the `Promise.all` should wait for `REQUEST1` `REQUEST2` `RECEIVE1` `RECEIVE2` to all come in before doing the `.then(console.log("fetched both"))`

Right now, it's does the `.then` after first 2 `REQUEST` are finished, not waiting for the 2 `RECEIVE` to come in.

[image]

I suspect it's the nested nature of the `requestUserPositions()` within the function that wraps `fetch()`

The `REQUEST` action is a simple function, and in the reducer it just flips an `isFetching` property to `true`:

```
function requestUserPositions(division) {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_USER_POSITIONS,
    division
  }
}
```

Sorry for this long issue but I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

This is a careless mistake

Turns out that when the `.then()` is wrapped inside a dispatch it gets executed simultaneously as the `Promise.all()` is being carried out.

The intended dispatch order was created by tagging the `then(()=>console.log` to the last dispatch `dispatch(fetchAllPositions(selectedUserDivision))` done from `ComponentDidMount`